# Firebase is not integrated properly in my Flutter android release builds

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

Firebase authentication with google signin is getting crashed in my release build app in  playstore, however its working fine in local.
I had already added release signing keys, app signing from play console in firebase console and all class libraries in my build.gradle file(firebase-auth,proguard rules, firestore), still I am seeing this exception

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (24.0.1).
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.w0.x.b(:19)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.w0.f.run(:2)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

in firebase Crashlytics. I will also add the build.gradle files. Could anyone pls help me?
I tried some of the suggestions from stackoverflow and other forums, but no luck.

1)pubspec.yaml

[image]

2)
[image: Android app build.gradle]

3)build.gradle

[image: removed some user info lines]

Answer (score 0):

Follow this documentation
https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#publishing-to-the-google-play-store

make sure you have all the permissions in res/AndroidManifest (not the debug/AndroidManifest).  res/AndroidManifest is used for production!